# making my custom made tumblr mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, mobile

Im trying to make my tumblr mobile friendly. As in when i go to the site on a mobile it will look and act the same as the main site but then smaller. 
At the moment its way too big. I have tried making @media codes in and out of .css. 
I have also added the:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
```

(with no luck.)

I think ive come to my end with it and I serious need help.
I dont want to spend money on buying a monthly site just to convert it as i'm sure there is a way out (but i just haven't found it yet )
My coding skills are quite new (so please break it down)  but im a fast learner ;)

the site: [www.wordlessmedia.com](http://www.wordlessmedia.com)

Comment: Depending how the site was designed, making it mobile friendly can be a challenge - Bootstraps framework makes it easy, but converting to bootstrap could be a challenge.

Comment: Thank you. I looked in to bootstrap and literally have no idea where to start :s it just gave me a bunch of files. the site is a original tumble theme that have just been customized. i thought maybe ive placed a code wrong :s

Comment: `width=device-width` is really useful, but you should use proportional css with it. A standard mobile screen is ~ 320px wide(iPhone web view standard), but your carousel is 1000px so it doesn't fit on the screen. You can hack the width by using 'width=1000' etc, but it doesn't work for every mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Making Tumblr blogs behave nice on mobile devices follows the same rules as with normale HTML pages; HTML as well as CSS have to be edited.

1. Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` or `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">` to your HTML template
2. Add a CSS with media queries; depending on your strategy you can use fluid layout or breakpoints

As a rule of thumb for a simple responsive CSS strategy:

1. Avoid setting absolute widths (e.g. use `%` instead of `px` pr `em`.)
2. If you have to set absolute widths, use media queries to change this widths to suit different display widths
3. If you have multiple elements next to each other, consider putting them in a single column for small screens.
4. A simple way of scaling images to fit the width of their respective container is `img, video {max-width:100%}`; this will scale images down if there is not enough space

See http://blog.3960.org/ for a live example of a responsive Tumblr blog (I have to admit that this is my blog :)). There is a small stylesheet at http://cdn.3960.org/_style/style.css, which defines some things fluid, and other things by settings breakpoints.

Comment: wow great! i'm going to try that out now. In the exciting stylesheet, there are some Media queries (but they dont work) shall i delete them and add my own mobile CSS or shalli leave the exciting one in the style sheet and ann my own mobile CSS anyway ( would it override the exciting one?) Ans ive placed the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> at the head of my html just after the <head>. Is that ok?

Comment: The position of the `<meta />`-thingy for viewport is up to you, as long as it is in the `<head>`. The `@media`-rules are optional and only necessary if you want to change the behavior of your page for certain resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) css framework, It's very easy to pick up and is designed to work with smartphones/tablets in mind ( + it looks amazing ).

Comment: Thank you. I looked in to bootstrap and literally have no idea where to start :s it just gave me a bunch of files. the site is a original tumblr theme that have just been customized. i thought maybe ive placed a code wrong :s –